# Elixir, convert binary to byte array

Tags: elixir

I have the following value in Elixir:
`<<140, 143, 153, 192, 237, 255, 10>>`
Binaries don't seem to be enumerable. I need to convert it to a list so I can iterate over it, byte-by-byte, something like:
`[140, 143, 153, 192, 237, 255, 10]`. I understand that to_char_array would do it if all the bytes were valid unicode characters but they aren't.

Just getting started with Elixir and really appreciate any suggestions for converting binaries to lists(byte arrays).

Comment: I just discovered this approach: 
`byte_array = for <<x::8 <- binary_data>>, do: x`

This seems to work but would be interested to see any other suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have a look at erlang's [bin_to_list/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#bin_to_list-1)

```
:binary.bin_to_list(<<140, 143, 153, 192, 237, 255, 10>>)
# [140, 143, 153, 192, 237, 255, 10]
```

Comment: Perfect, and much more readable than my initial solution. Thanks!